# How to get document according this document's sub document id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Product schema and a Category Schema.

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    categories: [CategorySchema],
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

How to get the product which contains a particular category. How to write this query using mongoose.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that you have a model definition for `Product` based on the `ProductSchema` definition then the general syntax is not much different from a standard mongoDB [**`.find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) query:

```
var categoryId; // As whatever the desired value of the ObjectId is

Product.find({ "categories._id": categoryId }, function(err,product) {

  // Work with found document or err object here

});
```

So this is just a simple "dot notation" form of the query in order to reference the sub-document element.

Of course your schema structure also appears to be based on [embedded documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html) so that means you should be able to access any of the other properties of that schema as well:

```
Product.find({ "categories.name": "category name" }, function(err,product) {

  // Work with found document or err object here

});
```

For solutions that have the `CategorySchema` objects within their own model collection, there is also the [**`.poulate()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method which provides an effective, if not quite as efficient alternative to embedding where embedding is not practical.